# Python - is it possible to get logging.handlers.httpHandler to set the content header to JSON without resorting to custom code?

Tags: python, json, logging, configuration, httphandler

I'd like to use Python's logging.handlers.HTTPHandler to send log events using POST with the log events in a JSON format. However I don't want to resort to writing extensions - so the configuration could be implemented either using file OR by code.  I wrote the following code to configure the logger and send a test message.  The event is being received but doesn't appear to have the content type set to JSON

```
import logging, logging.handlers
testHandler = logging.handlers.HTTPHandler('localhost:18080', '/test', method='POST')
log = logging.getLogger("me")
log.addHandler(testHandler)
log.warn ('{"beep":"beep"}')
```

Have I missed a configuration?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, and especially so when you use the POST method. The HTTPHandler is [hardcoded](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L1218) to set the content type header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for all POST requests.

The best you can do is subclass the HTTPHandler and implement a custom version of the `emit()` method.